# What is the algorithm used to interpolate in Matlab's imresize function?

Tags: matlab, interpolation, octave

I am using the Matlab/Octave `imresize()` function which resamples a given 2D array. I want to understand how a particular interpolation algorithm used in `imresize` works.

(I am using octave on windows)

e.g.

```
A =  1 2 
     3 4
```

is a 2D array. Then I use the command

```
b=imresize(a,2,'linear');
```

basically upsampling row and columns by 2.

The output is

```
1.0000   1.3333   1.6667   2.0000
1.6667   2.0000   2.3333   2.6667
2.3333   2.6667   3.0000   3.3333
3.0000   3.3333   3.6667   4.0000
```

I don't understand how this linear interpolation is working. It is said to use <strike>bi</strike>linear interpolation, but how does it pad the data at boundaries and how does it get the output that it is getting?

Second example: 
For

```
A = 

1   2   3   4
5   6   7   8
0   1   2   3
1   2   3   4
```

how does `imresize(a,1.5,'linear')` give the following output?

```
1.00000   1.60000   2.20000   2.80000   3.40000   4.00000
3.40000   4.00000   4.60000   5.20000   5.80000   6.40000
4.00000   4.60000   5.20000   5.80000   6.40000   7.00000
1.00000   1.60000   2.20000   2.80000   3.40000   4.00000
0.40000   1.00000   1.60000   2.20000   2.80000   3.40000
1.00000   1.60000   2.20000   2.80000   3.40000   4.00000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see, in your example, each corner point is one of your original input values.

The intermediate values are derived via [*linear interpolation*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation) in each direction.  So for instance, to calculate `b(3,2)`:

- `b(1,2)` is 1/3 of the way between `b(1,1)` and `b(1,4)`.  So:

  ```
  b(1,2) = (1/3)*b(1,4) + (2/3)*b(1,1)
  ```
- `b(4,2)` is 1/3 of the way between `b(4,1)` and `b(4,4)`.  So:

  ```
  b(4,2) = (1/3)*b(4,4) + (2/3)*b(4,1)
  ```
- `b(3,2)` is 2/3 of the way between `b(1,2)` and `b(4,2)`.  So:

  ```
  b(3,2) = (2/3)*b(4,2) + (1/3)*b(1,2)
  ```

Comment: @Oli - Thanks. I get it. I assume, The calculation of weights for a different scaling factor would take the appropriate values. i.e. For my example the weights were 0.33,0.66 since 2 given samples were to be interpolated to 4 samples total, if it was 2 samples to be interpolated to total N samples, weights would be 1/(N-1), 2/(N-1) isn't it?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth - Edited OP to add a second example which resamples by a fractional scaling factor,. In that case not clear how it comptued its outputs. Can u pls. check above.

Comment: @Oli - Any inputs about the second example which I added in OP?

Comment: @Oli - also in you edited answer points b(4,2) and b(3,2) computations look incorrect (weights swapped) to me. Isn't it?

Comment: @goldenmean: Yes, good spot, I had that last calculation back to front!

Comment: @Oli - Any inputs about the second example which I added in OP?

Comment: @Golden: it is *still* linear interpolation for your second example - you might be confused because the weights involved are all based on the factor (1/5), which is (one over) the desired output size minus 1.

Answer (score 2):

The following code shows how to perform [bilinear interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_interpolation) using [INTERP2](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp2.html):

```
A = [1 2; 3 4];
SCALE = 2;

xi = linspace(1,size(A,2),SCALE*size(A,2));  %# interpolated horizontal positions
yi = linspace(1,size(A,1),SCALE*size(A,1));  %# interpolated vertical positions
[X Y] = meshgrid(1:size(A,2),1:size(A,1));   %# pixels X-/Y-coords
[XI YI] = meshgrid(xi,yi);                   %# interpolated pixels X-/Y-coords
B = interp2(X,Y,A, XI,YI, '*linear');        %# interp values at these positions
```

the result agrees with your Octave code output:

```
B =
            1       1.3333       1.6667            2
       1.6667            2       2.3333       2.6667
       2.3333       2.6667            3       3.3333
            3       3.3333       3.6667            4
```

---

I should mention that I'm getting different results between [MATLAB](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imresize.html) and [Octave](https://octave.sourceforge.io/image/function/imresize.html) IMRESIZE output. For example, this is what I get when I execute the following in MATLAB on the matrix `A=[1 2; 3 4]`:

```
>> B = imresize([1 2; 3 4], 2, 'bilinear')
B =
            1         1.25         1.75            2
          1.5         1.75         2.25          2.5
          2.5         2.75         3.25          3.5
            3         3.25         3.75            4
```

which suggests that MATLAB's implementation is doing something extra... Unfortunately it's not easy to read the IMRESIZE source code, especially since at some point it calls a MEX-compiled function (with no source code form available).

As a side note, there seems to be a older version of this function as well: IMRESIZE_OLD (purely implemented in m-code). From what I could understand, it performs some sort of affine transformation on the image. Perhaps someone more familiar with the technique could shed some light on the subject...

---

## EDIT (2021)

Please refer to [John's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67044266/97160) for a more thorough explanation.

Comment: My guess is Matlab runs a Gaussian filter on the input data before upsampling. Octave does not do that(Although octave mentions that in the help imresize, but does not do that, when I checked.

Comment: @goldenmean: that would explain the difference. In any case, and to answer your original question, the Wikipedia article I linked to explains well the bilinear interpolation process with an example..

Comment: I took a second look at the IMRESIZE function, please read my answer to this other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7758078/resizing-in-matlab-w-different-filters/7759981#7759981

Comment: The version of imresize in Octave is doing it wrong and imresize in MATLAB is doing it right. The key is that the 2x2 image has its top left corner at (0.5, 0.5) and the bottom right corner at (2.5, 2.5). This area is separated in 2-by-2 pixels. Then you want to spread it to 4-by-4 pixels, meaning the new pixel centers are at 0.75, 1.25, 1.75 and 2.25 in terms of the old coordinates. This is what you need in `xi` and `yi`. See also at this bug report: https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?51769

Comment: @John I see, thank you for clarifying. So to fix the first code sample above (at least for `SCALE=2`), it would be something like this: https://pastebin.com/jYEhr8nt . The output should now match MATLAB's `imresize` except on the edges which come out as NA/NaN (we need to do the whole padding dance to get it). Correct? (I don't have access to MATLAB/Octave, so I tested [online](https://octave-online.net/))

Comment: @Amro Yes, exactly. I simplified your script a bit and added padding and also imresize for comparison, see [snippet here](https://gitlab.com/-/snippets/2099706). Note, that imresize in [Octave online](https://octave-online.net/) is currently wrong, the patch to fix it has been [submitted](http://hg.code.sf.net/p/octave/image/rev/49c01ed59b61) just yesterday.

Comment: @John nice, consider posting your code+explanation as a new answer, you definitely have my upvote :)

Comment: @Amro OK, I have added an answer with lots of explanations and pixel art. It was quite a bit of work. Thanks for the discussion here!

Answer (score 2):

## TL;DR

The results are wrong, because there was a bug in GNU Octave's `imresize`. It has been fixed recently for bilinear interpolation ([bug report](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?51769), [commit](http://hg.code.sf.net/p/octave/image/rev/49c01ed59b61)). Scroll down to "Interpolation of pixels" for the correct explanation how images are interpolated.

## Interpolation of samples

Let's start with linear interpolation of samples:

```
  0   1/3  2/3   1
  |    |    |    |
a=1----+----+----2=b
```

You blend over from a to b by using

f(x) = (1 - x) * a + x * b.

Some examples:

- f(0) = (1 - 0) * a + 0 * b = a = 1
- f(1/3) = (1 - 1/3) * a + 1/3 * b = 2/3 + 2/3 = 4/3 = 1.3333
- f(1/2) = (1 - 1/2) * a + 1/2 * b = (a + b) / 2 = 1.5
- f(2/3) = (1 - 2/3) * a + 2/3 * b = 1/3 + 4/3 = 5/3 = 1.6667
- f(1) = (1 - 1) * a + 1 * b = b = 2

This corresponds to the first line of your first example. In bilinear interpolation the simple linear interpolation is used in x or y direction. In general simple linear interpolation is not used in diagonal or any other direction (your first example is a degenerate case).

```
       0   1/3        1
       |    |    |    |
 0   a=1---f(x)--+----2=b
       |    |    |    |
      -+----+----+----+-
       |    |    |    |
2/3   -+---???---+----+-
       |    |    |    |
 1   c=3---g(x)--+----4=d
       |    |    |    |
```

How are the other points calculated then? We use the simple linear interpolation for top and bottom row in x direction and then interpolate the results in y direction:

- In x-direction, top row: f(x) = (1 - x) * a + x * b, example: f(1/3) = 4/3 = 1.3333
- In x-direction, bottom row: g(x) = (1 - x) * c + x * d, example: g(1/3) = 10/3 = 3.3333
- In y-direction, interpolation column: h(y) = (1 - y) * f(x) + y * g(x), example: h(2/3) = 8/3 = 2.6667

Looking at the last equation, we could also put in f(x) and g(x) and get:

h(x, y) = (1 - x) * (1 - y) * a + x * (1 - y) * b + (1 - x) * y * c + x * y * d

This is what you got.

In the second example the points are just a bit different, because you transform from 4 points to 6 in each direction:

```
old: 0         1         2         3 (sample grid)
     |         |         |         |
     +-----+---+-+-----+-+---+-----+
     |     |     |     |     |     |
new: 0    3/5   6/5   9/5  12/5    3 (interpolation grid)
```

This is valid for x and y direction in your second example. To use the formula above, you must map each square to [0, 1] x [0, 1].

That's theory. Octave uses `interp2` for bilinear interpolation internally. To use `interp2` you specify the matrix with samples and the grid that defines the interpolation points:

```
A = [1, 2;
     3, 4];
xi = linspace(1, size(A, 2), 4);
yi = linspace(1, size(A, 1), 4)';
B = interp2(A, xi, yi)
```

This gives the results you got, **but they are wrong**!

## Interpolation of pixels

The basics for bilinear interpolation as explained above are still valid, but the interpolation grid is wrong. This is because an image does not consist of sample points, but of pixels. Pixels are areas represented by its mean value. So actually the pixels of the image look like this:

```
    0.5        1        1.5        2        2.5
0.5  +-------------------+-------------------+
     |                   |                   |
     |                   |                   |
     |                   |                   |
 1   |         o         |         o         |
     |                   |                   |
     |                   |                   |
     |                   |                   |
1.5  +-------------------+-------------------+
     |                   |                   |
     |                   |                   |
     |                   |                   |
 2   |         o         |         o         |
     |                   |                   |
     |                   |                   |
     |                   |                   |
2.5  +-------------------+-------------------+
```

So the top left pixel's area is [0.5, 1.5] x [0.5, 1.5] with its center at (1, 1). And what you want by upscaling with 2 are the following new pixels (in coordinate space of the old grid, since the image covers still the same area):

```
    0.5  0.75  1   1.25 1.5  1.75  2   2.25 2.5
0.5  +---------+---------+---------+---------+
     |         |         |         |         |
0.75 |    x    |    x    |    x    |    x    |
     |         |         |         |         |
 1   +---------o---------+---------o---------+
     |         |         |         |         |
1.25 |    x    |    x    |    x    |    x    |
     |         |         |         |         |
1.5  +---------+---------+---------+---------+
     |         |         |         |         |
1.75 |    x    |    x    |    x    |    x    |
     |         |         |         |         |
 2   +---------o---------+---------o---------+
     |         |         |         |         |
2.25 |    x    |    x    |    x    |    x    |
     |         |         |         |         |
2.5  +---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

Now you take the new centers `x` as interpolation grid and the old centers `o` as sample grid. You see, that the new border pixels actually need extrapolation. We assume that it extrapolates constant, so we could pad the array to make an interpolation again or limit the interpolation grid. As code using `interp2` you can do:

```
A = [1, 2;
     3, 4];
xi = linspace(0.75, 2.25, 4);
yi = linspace(0.75, 2.25, 4)';
xi(xi < 1) = 1; xi(xi > 2) = 2;
yi(yi < 1) = 1; yi(yi > 2) = 2;
B = interp2(A, xi, yi)
```

[Here is a more general solution](https://gitlab.com/-/snippets/2099706) (only valid for integer output sizes), inspired by Amro's comments below [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6445490/2414411). If you allow scale factors that result in floating point output size.

On non-integer output sizes the number of new pixels will be such that the last pixel overlaps. So for example with a scale factor of 5/4 = 1.25 the pixel size will be 1 / (5/4) = 4/5 = 0.8. Hence, scaling a 2x2 image with 1.25 yields a 3x3 image. The old pixel centers (sample grid) are at 1 and 2 and the new pixel centers (interpolation grid) are at 0.9, 1.7 and 2.5.

```
    0.5                 1.5                 2.5
     |         1         |         2         |
old: +---------o---------+---------o---------+
new: +-------x-------+-------x-------+-------x-------+
     |      0.9      |      1.7      |      2.5      |
    0.5             1.3             2.1             2.9
```

Here is some code to show this:

```
img = [1, 2;
       3, 4];

% make interpolation grid
scale = 1.25
pixel_size = 1 / scale
out_size = ceil(size(img) / pixel_size)
xi = 0.5 + pixel_size / 2 + (0:out_size(1)-1) / scale
yi = 0.5 + pixel_size / 2 + (0:out_size(2)-1) / scale

% limit interpolation grid to sample grid bounds
xi(xi < 1) = 1;   xi(xi > size(img, 2)) = size(img, 2)
yi(yi < 1) = 1;   yi(yi > size(img, 1)) = size(img, 1)

% interpolate
scaled_interp = interp2(img, xi, yi', 'linear')

% Octave's imresize does not support anti-aliasing yet
scaled_resize_octave = imresize(img, scale, 'bilinear')
% Matlab's imresize uses anti-aliasing for downscaling, switch off to keep is simple
scaled_resize_matlab = imresize(img, scale, 'bilinear', 'Antialiasing', false)

% yields:
%    1.0000    1.7000    2.0000
%    2.4000    3.1000    3.4000
%    3.0000    3.7000    4.0000
```

That's all for resizing with bilinear interpolation. For bicubic interpolation Matlab uses symmetric padding and a convolutional algorithm that weights a 4x4 neighborhood. Octave behaves differently ([patch incoming](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/index.php?60322)).

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to share this, very useful (I'll be referring to it whenever I forget all these details)! Reading "interpolation of samples" section and the last part reminded me of a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26828782/97160) where we looked at the bicubic interpolation and the implementation difference between MATLAB and OpenCV (in that case it was the constant `a=-0.5` vs `a=-0.75`, and seeing the above bug report it seems Octave also has a different constant value chosen)

Comment: @Amro I saw this question and there are even similar ones, where people think Matlab uses `a = -1`, but `a=-0.5` is correct. Octave does not use the convolutional bicubic interpolation algorithm at all. So there is no `a` to determine to get the Octave method. The patch is currently for `imresize` and `imrotate` only. Maybe the changes can be shifted to `interp2`, but there is not even a bug report yet, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

I adapted MATLAB's `imresize` function for Java:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MatlabResize {
    private static final double TRIANGLE_KERNEL_WIDTH = 2;

    public static double[][] resizeMatlab(double[][] data, int out_y, int out_x) {
        double scale_x = ((double)out_x)/data[0].length;
        double scale_y = ((double)out_y)/data.length;

        double[][][] weights_indizes = contribution(data.length, out_y, scale_y, TRIANGLE_KERNEL_WIDTH);
        double[][] weights = weights_indizes[0];
        double[][] indices = weights_indizes[1];

        final double[][] result = new double[out_y][data[0].length];
        double value = 0;

        for (int p=0; p<result[0].length; p++) {
            for (int i=0; i<weights.length; i++) {
                value = 0;

                for (int j=0; j<indices[0].length; j++) {
                    value += weights[i][j] * data[(int)indices[i][j]][p];
                }

                result[i][p] = value;
            }
        }

        weights_indizes = contribution(data[0].length, out_x, scale_x, TRIANGLE_KERNEL_WIDTH);
        weights = weights_indizes[0];
        indices = weights_indizes[1];

        final double[][] result2 = new double[result.length][out_x];
        for (int p=0; p<result.length; p++) {
            for (int i=0; i<weights.length; i++) {
                value = 0;

                for (int j=0; j<indices[0].length; j++) {
                    value += weights[i][j] * result[p][(int)indices[i][j]];
                }

                result2[p][i] = value;
            }
        }

        return result2;
    }

    public static double[][] resizeMatlab(double[][] data, double scale) {
        int out_x = (int)Math.ceil(data[0].length * scale);
        int out_y = (int)Math.ceil(data.length * scale);

        double[][][] weights_indizes = contribution(data.length, out_y, scale, TRIANGLE_KERNEL_WIDTH);
        double[][] weights = weights_indizes[0];
        double[][] indices = weights_indizes[1];

        final double[][] result = new double[out_y][data[0].length];
        double value = 0;

        for (int p=0; p<result[0].length; p++) {
            for (int i=0; i<weights.length; i++) {
                value = 0;

                for (int j=0; j<indices[0].length; j++) {
                    value += weights[i][j] * data[(int)indices[i][j]][p];
                }

                result[i][p] = value;
            }
        }

        weights_indizes = contribution(data[0].length, out_x, scale, TRIANGLE_KERNEL_WIDTH);
        weights = weights_indizes[0];
        indices = weights_indizes[1];

        final double[][] result2 = new double[result.length][out_x];
        for (int p=0; p<result.length; p++) {
            for (int i=0; i<weights.length; i++) {
                value = 0;

                for (int j=0; j<indices[0].length; j++) {
                    value += weights[i][j] * result[p][(int)indices[i][j]];
                }

                result2[p][i] = value;
            }
        }

        return result2;
    }


    private static double[][][] contribution(int length, int output_size, double scale, double kernel_width) {
        if (scale < 1.0) {
            kernel_width = kernel_width/scale;
        }

        final double[] x = new double[output_size];
        for (int i=0; i<x.length; i++) {
            x[i] = i+1;
        }

        final double[] u = new double[output_size];
        for (int i=0; i<u.length; i++) {
            u[i] = x[i]/scale + 0.5*(1 - 1/scale);
        }

        final double[] left = new double[output_size];
        for (int i=0; i<left.length; i++) {
            left[i] = Math.floor(u[i] - kernel_width/2);
        }

        int P = (int)Math.ceil(kernel_width) + 2;

        final double[][] indices = new double[left.length][P];
        for (int i=0; i<left.length; i++) {
            for (int j=0; j<=P-1; j++) {
                indices[i][j] = left[i] + j;
            }
        }

        double[][] weights = new double[u.length][indices[0].length];
        for (int i=0; i<u.length; i++) {
            for (int j=0; j<indices[i].length; j++) {
                weights[i][j] = u[i] - indices[i][j];
            }
        }

        if (scale < 1.0) {
            weights = triangleAntiAliasing(weights, scale);
        } else {
            weights = triangle(weights);
        }

        double[] sum = Matlab.sum(weights, 2);
        for (int i=0; i<weights.length; i++) {
            for (int j=0; j<weights[i].length; j++) {
                weights[i][j] = weights[i][j] / sum[i];
            }
        }

        for (int i=0; i<indices.length; i++) {
            for (int j=0; j<indices[i].length; j++) {
                indices[i][j] = Math.min(Math.max(indices[i][j], 1.0), length);
            }
        }

        sum = Matlab.sum(weights, 1);
        int a = 0;

        final List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int i=0; i<sum.length; i++) {
            if (sum[i] != 0.0) {
                a++;
                list.add(i);
            }
        }

        final double[][][] result = new double[2][weights.length][a];
        for (int i=0; i<weights.length; i++) {
            for (int j=0; j<list.size(); j++) {
                result[0][i][j] = weights[i][list.get(j)];
            }
        }
        for (int i=0; i<indices.length; i++) {
            for (int j=0; j<list.size(); j++) {
                result[1][i][j] = indices[i][list.get(j)]-1; //java indices start by 0 and not by 1
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    private static double[][] triangle(final double[][] x) {
        for (int i=0; i<x.length; i++) {
            for (int j=0; j<x[i].length; j++) {
                if (-1.0 <= x[i][j] && x[i][j] < 0.0) {
                    x[i][j] = x[i][j] + 1;
                } else if (0.0 <= x[i][j] &&  x[i][j] < 1.0) {
                    x[i][j] = 1 - x[i][j];
                } else {
                    x[i][j] = 0;
                }
            }
        }

        return x;
    }

    private static double[][] triangleAntiAliasing(final double[][] x, final double scale) {
        for (int i=0; i<x.length; i++) {
            for (int j=0; j<x[i].length; j++) {
                x[i][j] = x[i][j] * scale;
            }
        }

        for (int i=0; i<x.length; i++) {
            for (int j=0; j<x[i].length; j++) {
                if (-1.0 <= x[i][j] && x[i][j] < 0.0) {
                    x[i][j] = x[i][j] + 1;
                } else if (0.0 <= x[i][j] &&  x[i][j] < 1.0) {
                    x[i][j] = 1 - x[i][j];
                } else {
                    x[i][j] = 0;
                }
            }
        }

        for (int i=0; i<x.length; i++) {
            for (int j=0; j<x[i].length; j++) {
                x[i][j] = x[i][j] * scale;
            }
        }

        return x;
    }
}
```

Comment: So are you saying your code is equivalent to the MATLAB `imresize` code? Did you somehow reverse-engineer the MEX-compiled function that Amro mentioned? Or did you just in general implement a similar functionality without verifying that it produces identical results in different corner cases?

Comment: Hm.. equivalent.. :) I tried to understand the `imresize` function in MATLAB and port it for JAVA. (The sourcecode of this function is readable). With this function i got (for 600x600 matrices resized to 192x192) the same results like in MATLAB. But i didn't tested it with unit-tests.