# How does nearest neighbor interpolation work in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, interpolation, image-resizing, nearest-neighbor

I want to find out how nearest neighbor interpolation works in MATLAB. I have input data :

```
A = [1 4 7 4 3 6]     % 6 digit vector
```

I use the following MATLAB code :

```
B = imresize(A,[1 9],'nearest');
```

I get the following result :

```
[1,4,4,7,4,4,3,6,6]
```

Solving by hand, I get this result :

```
[1 4 4 7 4 4 3 3 6]
```

Can you please guide me? Am I going wrong somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you apply regular interpolation using `interp1`, it will give you the result you computed by hand:

```
>> N = 9;
>> B = interp1(linspace(0,1,numel(A)), A, linspace(0,1,N), 'nearest')
B =
     1     4     4     7     4     4     3     3     6
```

Some time ago, I went through the source code of IMRESIZE trying to understand how it works. [See this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7759981) for a summary. At some point the code will call an private MEX-function (no corresponding source code available), but the comments are enough to understand the implementation.

For what it's worth, there an also a function `imresize_old` which provides an older implementation of `imresize` (used in version R2006b and earlier). It gave yet another different result:

```
>> B = imresize(A, [1 N], 'nearest')
B =
     1     4     4     7     4     4     3     6     6

>> B = imresize_old(A, [1 N], 'nearest')
B =
     1     4     4     7     7     4     3     6     6
```

What's more [it was previously observed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6445490) that the implementation between [MATLAB](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imresize.html) and [Octave](http://octave.sourceforge.net/image/function/imresize.html) also differed in some cases.

---

## EDIT:

[image: interpolation]

As you noted, in some cases you have to be mindful about floating-point limitations when working with [`interp1`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html). So we could do the interpolation by choosing x-numbers to be between `[0,1]` range, or a more stable range like `[1,numel(A)]`. Because of rounding errors in edge cases, this might give different results.

For example compare the two codes below:

```
% interpolation in [0,1]
N = 11;
y = [1 4 7 4 3 6];
x = linspace(0,1,numel(y));
xi = linspace(0,1,N);
yi = interp1(x, y, xi, 'nearest');

% print numbers with extended precision
fprintf('%.17f %g\n',[x;y])
fprintf('%.17f %g\n',[xi;yi])
```

against:

```
% interpolation in [1,k]
N = 11;
y = [1 4 7 4 3 6];
x = 1:numel(y);
xi = linspace(1,numel(y),N);
yi = interp1(x, y, xi, 'nearest');

% print numbers with extended precision
fprintf('%.17f %g\n',[x;y])
fprintf('%.17f %g\n',[xi;yi])
```

Here is the output nicely formatted:

```
--------------------------------------------------------
       [0,1] RANGE        |         [1,k] RANGE
--------------------------------------------------------     
        xi           yi   |            xi            yi
--------------------------------------------------------
0.00000000000000000  1    |     1.00000000000000000  1 |
0.20000000000000001  4    |     2.00000000000000000  4 |
0.40000000000000002  7    |     3.00000000000000000  7 |
0.59999999999999998  4    |     4.00000000000000000  4 |  INPUT
0.80000000000000004  3    |     5.00000000000000000  3 |
1.00000000000000000  6    |     6.00000000000000000  6 |
--------------------------------------------------------
0.00000000000000000  1    |     1.00000000000000000  1 |
0.10000000000000001  4    |     1.50000000000000000  4 |
0.20000000000000001  4    |     2.00000000000000000  4 |
0.29999999999999999  4    |     2.50000000000000000  7 |
0.40000000000000002  7    |     3.00000000000000000  7 |
0.50000000000000000  4    |     3.50000000000000000  4 | OUTPUT
0.59999999999999998  4    |     4.00000000000000000  4 |
0.69999999999999996  4    |     4.50000000000000000  3 |
0.80000000000000004  3    |     5.00000000000000000  3 |
0.90000000000000002  6    |     5.50000000000000000  6 |
1.00000000000000000  6    |     6.00000000000000000  6 |
--------------------------------------------------------
```

So you can see that some numbers are not exactly representable in double-precision when working in the [0,1] range. So 0.3 which is supposed to be in the middle [0.2, 0.4], turns to be closer to the lower end 0.2 than 0.4 because of roundoff error. While on the other side, 2.5 is exactly in the middle of [2,3] (all numbers exactly represented), and is assigned to the upper end 3 using nearest neighbor.

Also be aware that [`colon`](http://web.archive.org/web/20120917082349/http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-4FLI96/index.html?solution=1-4FLI96) and [`linspace`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/linspace.html) can produce different outputs sometimes:

```
>> (0:0.1:1)' - linspace(0,1,11)'
ans =
            0
            0
            0
   5.5511e-17
            0
            0
            0
            0
            0
            0
            0
```

Comment: If N=11, then there is an ambiguity selecting the nearest neighbor.. what does this function do then?

Comment: Try it. Interestingly MATLAB and Octave gave different results for N=11 using `interp1`: http://ideone.com/TMP1bR

Comment: @sanjay_c0d3r: I added a section about floating-point errors, see my edit above

Answer (score 1):

NN is the simplest form of interpolation. It has the following recipe: use the value at the nearest sample location. The NN interpolation in MATLAB is computationally efficient but if you need more accuracy, I recommend you to use the bilinear or the bicubic interpolation. You can also check **interp1()** instead.

Here provides an explanation with an example: http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ug/interpolation-methods.html

Answer (score 0):

I have no reference for this so I suggest you test it against other examples using `imresize` but I can recover Mat;ab's values like this.

Assume that `A` represents `y` values and the positions of elements in `A` represent `x` values. so now

```
n = length(A);
N = 9;

x = 1:n %// i.e. 1:6
```

now we need to find interpolating position i.e. `xi` points. I would have done it like this:

```
xi = round((1:N)/N)*n
```

which gives

```
xi =

   1   1   2   3   3   4   5   5   6
```

which results in a `yi` of

```
yi = A(xi)

yi =

   1   1   4   7   7   4   3   3   6
```

which differs from both yours and Matlab's answers (how did you get yours?)

So then I tried:

```
xi = round(((0:N-1)/N)*n)+1
yi = A(xi)
```

which makes just as much sense and gets me Matlab's result of

```
yi =

   1   4   4   7   4   4   3   6   6
```

So I'm guessing that's how they do it. But I don't have `imresize` to test other cases